# Reduce time taken for GC_FOR_ALLOC

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, android-memory

In my app, loads of images are loaded which results in many GC_FOR_ALLOC calls.

Each call takes 100ms+ which results in choppy animations.

I've taken all the steps I can (re-use of bitmap memory, caching) to reduce the number of calls, but now I'd like to reduce the actual time taken per GC_FOR_ALLOC call.

Are there any quick wins to be had in this matter? If my understanding is correct, GC_FOR_ALLOC first looks for `SoftReferences` to be freed, and then traverses the reference tree to free up objects.

Is the only answer to reduce my memory footprint, so that traversing the tree takes less time?

Comment: In my experience, two big offenders in causing repeated GC_FOR_ALLOC are (1) improper view reuse in ListView and (2) allocations in onDraw()/onMeasure(). You probably have that covered, but worth mentioning just in case.

Comment: @matiash I'm not actually overriding onDraw/onMeasure anywhere. I'm almost certain the GC_FOR_ALLOC is taking place every time I call  BitmapFactory.decodeStream and there is no available bitmap to be re-used. Thanks though